# Protractor UnknownError: Connection reset

Tags: selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm not able to run my test cases in protractor.
It opens chrome window, write data; in the URL section but then it crashes.
Did you know why I get this error?

```
Running "protractor:current" (protractor) task
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Session created: count=1, browserName=chrome
Exception thrown: Keeping the Selenium server alive

C:\Users\210080088\Documents\Github\performance-central\app\src\main\resources\static\node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108
var template = new Error(this.message);
             ^
UnknownError: Connection reset
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you are using some sort or task runner like gulp or grunt.

Gulp:

You might be using https://github.com/mllrsohn/gulp-protractor

Update this to version 3.0.0 `npm update gulp-protractor`

Then update webdrivers using this task `https://github.com/mllrsohn/gulp-protractor#protractor-webdriver` example is in examples section of source

Grunt:

You might be using https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner

Update this to version 4.0.0 `npm update grunt-protractor-runner`

`https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner#optionswebdrivermanagerupdate`

Use this option to update your webdrivers each time the task is run

Comment: After 72 hours battling this error, this is the answer. The thing is that my package.json has a '2.x' version of gulp-protractor. First I had the idea that it was protractor or the driver, but they do work fin when run outside gulp. That led me to this question, and that is the answer.
Now I should really update all the node package dependencies to avoid errors.
I would mark your answer as the best if I could.

Answer (score 2):

We just need to update the gulp plugins to latest version to support the Chrome54 & latest standalone Web-driver version

Update gulp-angular-protractor to version 0.2.0 
npm update gulp-angular-protractor or

npm install gulp-angular-protractor@0.2.0 (in my case update didn't work)

Update gulp-protractor to version 3.0.0 
npm update gulp-protractor

your gulp.js file should look like below & then you are good to go. let me know if you are still facing any issues. please excuse me if answer is not properly formatted.

```
var gulpAngularProtractor = require('gulp-angular-protractor');
 gulp.task('e2e', function(callback) {
     gulp.src(paths.tests)
         .pipe((gulpAngularProtractor ({
                 configFile: 'protractor.conf.js',
                 args: [
                   '--suite', args.suite
                 ],
         })).on('error', function(e) {
                 console.log(e);
             }).on('end', callback));
 });



 gulp.task('webdriver-update', gulpAngularProtractor .webdriver_update);
 gulp.task('webdriver-standalone', ['webdriver-update'], gulpAngularProtractor .webdriver_standalone);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with new version of chrome > 54 , Have a look [protractor#3639](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3639)

to get Details on the same  or try with chrome 53 or update webdriver-manager (which is not getting update you need to do it manually).